# Restructuring BigQuery output within Clojure

Tags: google-bigquery, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I'm trying to work with BigQuery (BQ) through Java interop. The dataset I'm using in BQ can be found [here](https://msi.nga.mil/api/publications/download?type=view&key=16920959/SFH00000/UpdatedPub150.csv) (**WARNING**: link to CSV file). I have the following code:

```
(ns bq
  (:import (com.google.cloud.bigquery BigQueryOptions QueryJobConfiguration BigQuery BigQueryException BigQuery$JobOption)))

(defn querybq [query]
  (let [^BigQuery big-query (.getService (BigQueryOptions/getDefaultInstance))
        ^QueryJobConfiguration query-config (.build (QueryJobConfiguration/newBuilder query))
        results (.query big-query query-config (into-array BigQuery$JobOption []))]
    results))

;; Dataset location: https://msi.nga.mil/api/publications/download?type=view&key=16920959/SFH00000/UpdatedPub150.csv
(def res (querybq (str "SELECT * FROM xxxxxxxxxx.wpi_dataset.wpi_table LIMIT 10")))

(defn print-res [args]
  (doseq [x (.iterateAll res)]
    (let [^String y (.getStringValue (.get x 0))]
      (println y))))
```

First, I query BigQuery and assign the result to `res`. Then, I call `print-res` which prints out the first column of data. There are two problems I have.

1. I use `.getStringValue` to get the value from the first column, but this column doesn't necessarily contain strings. (In fact, it doesn't - it contains numbers.) How do I automatically extract the data as its correct type?
2. This only prints the first column, but I want to refer to *all* columns. I believe I could do this with `doseq` and `range` if I knew how many columns there are. Can I figure out how many columns there are *without* a second query to the database (i.e., directly from `res`)?

---

**Context:** While I'm printing output here, ultimately I'm trying to extract the data so that I can throw it into a dataframe from `tech.ml.dataset`.

---

`deps.edn`

```
{:deps
 {com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery {:mvn/version "2.24.4"}}}
```

---

### Example of contents of `res`

```
#object[com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult 0x63d5874f TableResult{rows=[[FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=12500.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=B
 595 razil NE Coast -- 12470}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=Cameta}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value= }, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=BR CMA}, F
 596 ieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=Brazil}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=South Atlantic Ocean}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value= }, FieldValue{att
 597 ribute=PRIMITIVE, value=Sailing Directions Pub. 124 (Enroute) - East Coast of South America}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=https://msi.geo.nga.mil/api/pub
 598 lications/download?key=16694491/SFH00000/Pub124bk.pdf&type=view}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value= }, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value= }, FieldValue{at
 599 tribute=PRIMITIVE, value= }, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=gen01b}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=3.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=0.0},
 600  FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=7.9}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=14.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=0.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIV
 601 E, value=0.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=0.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=0.0}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=0.0}...
```

Comment: What is the value of `res`? And `print-res` doesn't use the value of `args` at all, because you call `(.iterateAll res)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @MartinPůda. I included the argument in `print-res` because when I ran the function from the `clj` command line (e.g., `clj -X bq/print-res`) it got upset if there was no argument present, even if it is redundant. `res` is a `TableResult` and I'll add some of its content to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own questions:

1. There is also a [`getValue()`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldValue#com_google_cloud_bigquery_FieldValue_getValue__) function that returns the field as an object.
2. I can get the number of columns from the schema (or from an individual row) using the `size()` function.

---

For others wrestling with how to handle the result of a BQ query in Clojure, here's what I came up with (on top of the code in the question).

There are three functions that actually do the work to 1) parse out each field for a row (`parse-row`), 2) pull the column names from the schema (`column-names`), and 3) apply the first two functions to all rows/columns, patch the results together, and turn the result into a [Tablecloth](https://github.com/scicloj/tablecloth) dataset(`bq-to-dataset`).

```
(defn parse-row [row]
  "Split each FieldValueList into its components"
  (let [indices (range (.size row))]
    (map #(.getValue (.get row %1)), indices)))

(defn column-names [table-result]
  "Get column names from TableResult"
  (let [field-list (.getFields (.getSchema table-result))
        list-length (.size field-list)
        list-indices (range list-length)]
    (map #(.getName (.get field-list %1)) list-indices)))

(defn bq-to-dataset [table-result]
  "Convert a TableResult into a TMD dataset"
  (let [cols (map keyword (column-names table-result))]
    (->> table-result
         (.iterateAll)
         (map parse-row)
         (map #(zipmap (partial cols) %1))
         (tc/dataset))))
```

To demo this, we can pull a few columns and then print them.

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (-> (bq-to-dataset res)
       (tc/select-columns [:MainPortName :RegionName :WorldPortIndexNumber])
       (print)))
```

```
| :MainPortName |                 :RegionName | :WorldPortIndexNumber |                                                                                                     
|---------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------|                                                                                                     
|       Deering |   Alaska Continued -- 20185 |               20430.0 |                                                                                                     
|      Manistee |    US Lake Michigan -- 4570 |                4650.0 |                                                                                                     
|   Great Lakes |    US Lake Michigan -- 4570 |                4820.0 |                                                                                                     
|        Oconto |    US Lake Michigan -- 4570 |                5010.0 |                                                                                                     
|   Blind River |   Canada Lake Huron -- 3640 |                4200.0 |                                                                                                     
|  Presque Isle |    US Lake Superior -- 5230 |                5290.0 |                                                                                                     
|     Marquette |    US Lake Superior -- 5230 |                5280.0 |                                                                                                     
|      Wilmette |    US Lake Michigan -- 4570 |                4810.0 |                                                                                                     
|      Oakville | Canada Lake Ontario -- 2820 |                3020.0 |                                                                                                     
|    Belleville | Canada Lake Ontario -- 2820 |                2930.0 |
```